# Redis Enviornment Specific DB's

Tags: cache

I'm not entirely well versed in how Redis works, but I have an idea that it probably makes the most sense to have the 3 craft sites I have running on the same server, have 3 different redis databases assigned to each?

Is there a way to do so, like in `general.php` or `db.php`

As in

```
"site-one.com" => {
    'database' => 0,
},

"site-two.com" => {
    'database => 1,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set your [cacheMethod](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) config setting to 'redis' and create a `rediscache.php` file in `craft/config/`.

That config file is multi-environment aware, just like the other files in `craft/config/` and you can see the default settings for Redis in `craft/app/etc/config/defaults/rediscache.php`.