# Craft Cache Config - Remote Support?

Tags: plugin-development, config, cache, php, settings

Is there a way to configure Craft further beyond just settings like `'cacheMethod' => 'redis',`? I'm exploring the possibility of using Redis outside of the server Craft CMS is running on, and am curious if there is a way I can set this up while still using the built-in `craft()->cache` service.

I'd love to be able to utilize a remote cache option and configure it in the same way that cache has a `db.php`config file where you can set your database as local or remote.

Is there any information about doing this out there and/or plans to support this eventually? Just curious.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the Redis cache driver to use an external host, see the [config page](https://craftcms.com/classreference/etc/cache/RedisCache) for the documentation and [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/redis-enviornment-specific-dbs) for details on copying the default Redis config file and configuring it.

Long story short... Copy `craft/app/etc/config/defaults/rediscache.php` to your `craft/config/` folder and configure the settings as you wish.